# C function returns zero no matter what

Tags: c

So, for my first C project I wanted to start simple with a calculator, but all the function `SUM` does is return `0.00000`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int SUM (float n1, float n2);

int main() {
    float num1 = 0; 
    float num2 = 0;
    float res = 0;
    scanf("Enter 2 numbers: %f %f", &num1, &num2);
    res = SUM(num1, num2);
    printf ("%f", res);
}

int SUM (float n1, float n2) {
    float sum = n1+n2;
    return &sum;
}
```

Comment: why do you do `return &sum;` and not `return sum`;?

Comment: you are returning an address with the `&`, just do `return sum;` or even `return n1 + n2;` would be enough

Comment: You are [returning the address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/11683) of `sum`.

Comment: why do you use `return &sum`? why do return a `int` after summing `float`? why do you even use a new variable `sum`?

Comment: are you aware that ***sum*** is getting destroyed after the return call?

Comment: Did you enable all compiler warnings?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: @Toby Speight, Looks like `-Wwrite-strings` is subsumed by `-Wall`.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami.  I guess that wasn't the case when I added it to my standard flags.

Answer (score 7):

You declared that the `SUM` function will return an integer value (`int`).

Then you added two `float`s together, and returned the ***address*** of the result.

The address of a `float` is nothing like the value of an `int`.

You have invoked **Undefined Behavior**.

---

```
float SUM (float n1, float n2);   // SUM should return a float.


float SUM (float n1, float n2) {
    float sum = n1+n2;
    return sum;                   // Return the sum (without any addresses)
}
```

#### P.S.

You have a function named `SUM` (with capital letters), and a variable named `sum` with lowercase letters.   While this is technically OK, it may be a point of confusion if another programmer reads your code.
Can you *always* be sure of the difference between `Sum`, `sum`, `SUM`?  What about `Sine`, `sine`, `sin`, `Sin`, `SINE`, etc.?

You should put in extra effort to name your functions, variables, constants, etc clearly and unambiguously so that understanding and using the proper one in the proper context is easy for all programmers.

Comment: @TobySpeight:  Edit rejected.   C absolutely does have *addresses*; C lacks *references*.

Comment: There are a few passing mentions of addresses in the C standard, but there's no *address* type.  What we're talking about here is a *pointer* (which includes the type of the pointed-to object).  Re-read your copy of the standard if you're not convinced.

Comment: @TobySpeight *There are a few passing mentions* "[F]ew" is 79 in [the last draft of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), at least by the number on my browser search bar.  Along with 11 instances of the exact phrase "address of".

Comment: (cont) And [**6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) states "1 The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

2 The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.
Semantics
3 The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. ..."  The `&` operator yields an address that is a pointer type. Pointers **are** the C "address type"

Comment: @Andrew, that's exactly what I was getting at.  C uses pointers to implement addressing.